# TFS 2013 Upgrade - SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 Failure

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, tfs

I'm testing the upgrade of our on-premise TFS 2012.3 w/SharePoint Foundation 2010 installation to TFS 2013.RTM w/SharePoint Foundation 2013.  All goes well except for the SharePoint portion of the upgrade.

I'm checking the content database using Test-SPContentDatabase before the attachment upgrade and that yields errors like the following:

> Category        : MissingFeature
>   Error           : True
>   UpgradeBlocking : False
>   Message         : Database [WSS_Content] has reference(s) to a missing 
>                     feature: Id = [00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18], Name = 
>                     [Wiki Page Library], Description = [An interconnected set of 
>                     easily editable web pages, which can contain text, images 
>                     and web parts.], Install Location = [WebPageLibrary].
>   Remedy          : The feature with Id 00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18 is 
>                     referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not 
>                     installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause 
>                     upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains 
>                     the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.
>   Locations       :
>
> Category        : MissingWebPart
>   Error           : True
>   UpgradeBlocking : False
>   Message         : WebPart class [6210fe45-9e75-000c-7eb4-057beca81bf8] (class [
>                     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WebAccess.WebParts.RecentCheckinsWeb
>                     Part] from assembly 
>                     [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WebAccess.WebParts, 
>                     Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>                     PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]) is referenced [26] times 
>                     in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the 
>                     current farm. Please install any feature/solution which 
>                     contains this web part.
>   Remedy          : One or more web parts are referenced in the database 
>                     [WSS_Content], but are not installed on the current farm. 
>                     Please install any feature or solution which contains these 
>                     web parts.
>   Locations       :

The first error is very puzzling since I can find the feature Id in question by running the following command in the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell.

```
Get-SPFeature -Limit ALL | % { Get-SPFeature -Identity $_ | % { $_.DisplayName + "*"  + $_.GetTitle(1033) + "*" + $_.Scope + "*" + $_.Id + "*" + $_.GetDescription(1033)} } >> "C:\Features.csv"
```

There are 26 individual MissingFeature errors, which coincidentally is the number of Team Project portals in the site collection.

The second error makes more sense to me.  The Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WebAccess.WebParts version 11.0.0.0 assembly is not installed in the GAC on the server hosting SharePoint 2013.  The 12.0.0.0, TFS 2013, version is installed instead, as it should be I think.  Please note that I'm upgrading to new hardware.  This is not an in-place upgrade.  It may also be worth nothing that this SharePoint content was previously upgraded to SharePoint Foundation 2010 from WSS 3.0 SP2 and everything works fine on the 2010 site as I'm writing this.

If I do move forward with the attachment upgrade to this content database I'm left with web sites that simply state that 'an unexpected error occurred'.  This is just very strange because we hardly use the SharePoint support in TFS.  Nothing is customized.  Just seems like if this were an issue that crops up on such a simple setup I'd be able to find others with the same issue, but I've had no luck finding anyone else experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem here was driven by the fact that SharePoint 2013 has two modes (hives), 2010 (v14) and 2013 (v15).  Apparently, by default, a new SharePoint 2013 installation mostly only installs v15 features.  I'm not going to say that it doesn't install any v14 features but it didn't install the ones I needed.  I figured this out by using the [SharePoint Feature Admin Tool](http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/).  Very handy.  Armed with that knowledge, I found the cmdlets that I needed to run in the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell to install the missing v14 features.  I have done this by installing each missing feature individually and also by running the following cmdlet that installs all existing features in both the v14 or v15 hives.

```
Install-SPFeature -AllExistingFeatures
```

This is certainly the easier of the two methods since everything can be installed in one shot and it's the approach I used to move forward with my upgrade.